# Titanium/ArrowDB Query channels for token based push notification subsription

Tags: appcelerator, arrowdb

With Titanium is there a way for a mobile user to query push notification channels for his device if he has subscribed by device token ?
In the API there is a query function which requires querying but requires login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do exactly the required thing: http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications-method-query

But, to be honest, just a couple of hours ago I recognized that it only worked for me as long as I was admin user. For normal users it doesn't return the channels, I'm working on that topic to find the issue.

EDIT: Sorry, just read in your question you search for something without login, I think that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for answering, That's exactly what I ended up doing then. I created an admin account and I used it to query subscriptions by token

Comment: Hi @hini, today I just had another idea what the solution could be. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584821/query-push-subscriptions-without-results